# css is not loading in docker using nginix

Tags: php, codeigniter, docker, nginx

I am trying to run my codeigniter project in a docker. I have following app configuration in **docker-compose.yml**(only app part is shown below)

```
app:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html/codeigniter/
  depends_on:
    - db
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_HOST=db
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dummy
  ports:
    - 8080:81
```

in **var/www/html/codeigniter/app/nginx/default.conf** has the following content(nginx conf)

```
server {
   listen 81 default_server;
   listen [::]:81 default_server;
   server_name localhost;

   root /var/www/html/codeigniter;
   index index.html index.php;

   location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {}

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   }

   location ~* \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass app:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

while running **docker-compose up** command, it is loading the project. But showing 404 for css and js files. css folder path is /var/www/html/codeigniter/app/css/. What am I missing?

My folder structure

```
codeigniter
├── app
│   ├── application
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   ├── nginx
│   ├── system
│   ├── user_guide
│   └── vendor
│   └── Dockerfile
│   └── docker-composer.yml
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: your nginx configurtion seems to be a culprit here.

Comment: you may want to try this. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/

Comment: could you please point out the change that is needed. I could run the project without docker in the local having nginx the same configuration

Comment: Its working in local with nginx configuration, but usign docker its not working. I changed the nginx conf according to the link you have provided. But couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: can you show me /var/log/nginx/access.log

Comment: nginx_1       | 183.19.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2018:10:13:03 +0000] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost:81/show" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"

Comment: You can see the the path is /css/style.css and your  css path is /var/www/html/codeigniter/app/css/ so you may have to look into this either make app your root folder.

Comment: Do you mean to change root path in nginx conf file like this **root /var/www/html/test-science-data-manager/app**. But it is not loading even the html page, showing **File not found.** error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174405/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-choudhary-and-cr7).

Comment: Are the urls to your css files the same as your directory structure, eg `example.com/app/css/style.css` or are they different?

Comment: @miknik added folder structure. Pleas check

Comment: I need to know what the links in your html are like

Comment: my css link in html is http://localhost:81/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

I went through this problem and there was no use in tinkering with the nginx conf when I discovered that I should run:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

and

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

To only later see effects after changing conf nginx and then run:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

**Clear your web browser's cache, cookies, and history**

My conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;  ## Default: 1

worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  include  mime.types;

  index    index.html index.htm index.php;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts



    server {

            listen *:80;
            server_name my.devcom;

            error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

            root /www;
            index index.php;

            location = /favicon.ico {
                            log_not_found off;
                            access_log off;
                    }

            location = /robots.txt {
                            allow all;
                            log_not_found off;
                            access_log off;
                    }

            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

            }


            # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
            #
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root /var/lib/nginx/html;
            }

            # FastCGI 
            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass php:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            }

            location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }


    }
}
```